# Insert places Html in jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i have a little problem.
I want use codes html to change style of texts,but i don't can import it into Jquery Scripts.

```
$('body').append($('<p>').html( <p id="text2">Data:<p>'Data:'+["Data"]));
```

How i have to do?

Comment: @upvoters - why you put upvote for the question any reason?

Comment: What did you mean by palces

Comment: I want use codes html in script jQuery

Comment: insert tags html in script jquery

Comment: There are all sorts of syntax errors with the above code.  Did you check your js console?  Plus you are trying to nest a p inside a p - not valid html

Comment: try this: `$('body').append($('<p id="text2" />').html('Data:'+["Data"]));`

Answer (score 0):

If you mean styling the object with css then here you go:

```
$('body').append($('<p>').css('cssproperty','value);
```

If you mean appending html to your object I would do:

```
var myNewHtmlP = $('<p id="text2">Data:<p>'Data:'+["Data"])');

myNewHtmlP.appendTo($('body'));
```

Answer (score 0):

hey i think you search for this:

```
 $('body').append( $('<p/>').attr('id', 'text2' ).html('myTestText'));
```

first you append the p tag, the slash is very important, after that the p tag get the id "text2" and after that you write the text 'myTestText' in the p tag